# Yesod Custom RawSql

Tags: haskell, yesod, rawsql

Is it possible to create a custom rawSQL in yesod?

for example i have a Model for images

```
Images
    filename String
    description Text Maybe
    date UTCTime
    deriving Show
```

and i have a rawSQL query of

```
selectImages :: Handler [Entity Images]
selectImages = do
      runDB $ rawSql s []
      where s =  "SELECT ?? from images;"
```

but instead of this string query code `SELECT ?? from images;`. I would like to `SELECT id, CONCAT('upload/', filename) as path from images;`.

Hope you help me thank you in advance.

Comment: Not an answer to the question you're asking but I'd want to do that conversion in the application layer rather than at the database. Specifically I'd return the filename strings then prepend 'upload/' to them with a Haskell function.

Comment: thank you for you input :-)

i solve this today using the toJSON :)

Comment: Cool, remember to stick your solution in as an answer for the benefit of future viewers. Answering your own question is actively encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem using `toJSON` ,
This [Link](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/persistent/Database-Persist-Class.html) helps me alot also with the help of IRC #haskell, #yesod channel.